# How to make immutable jar file with help of java file?

Tags: java, jar, immutability

I want to make immutable jar file with help of java file.
Is it possible to make immutable jar?

Comment: "Is it possible" - no.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a deep research, I came to an conclusion that it is not possible to make a JAR immutable.

We can make a class immutable, but not jar

Comment: Depends on what you mean. Signing a JAR could let you tell if it has been changed in any way. Read more here:
 [Signing and Verifying JAR Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signindex.html)